# Parse String array into Int Matrix

Tags: c#, parsing

```
  string[] words;
  numOfMatrix = int.Parse(fileIn.ReadLine());

  nameOfMatrix1 = fileIn.ReadLine();
  words = fileIn.ReadLine().Split(' ');
  matrix1H = int.Parse(words[0]);
  matrix1W = int.Parse(words[1]);
  matrix1 = new int[matrix1H + 1, matrix1W + 1];
  for (int i = 1; i <= matrix1H; i++)
  {
    int k = 0;
    words = fileIn.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    for (int j = 1; j <= matrix1W; j++)
    {
      matrix1[i,j] = int.Parse(words[k]);
      k++;
    }
  }
```

**Input Sample Data**

```
3
Matrix One
5 7
45   38    5   56   18   34    4
87   56   23   41   75   87   97
45   97   86    7    6    8   85
67    6   79   65   41   37    4
 7   76   57   68    8   78    2
Matrix Two
6 8
45   38    5   56   18   34    4   30
87   56   23   41   75   87   97   49
45   97   86    7    6    8   85   77
67    6   79   65   41   37    4   53
 7   76   57   68    8   78    2   14
21   18   46   99   17    3   11   73
Matrix Three
6 6
45   38    5   56   18   34
87   56   23   41   75   87
45   97   86    7    6    8
67    6   79   65   41   37
 7   76   57   68    8   78
21   18   46   99   17    3
```

Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Int32.Parse(String s)

On the line where I parse words[k] into matrix1[i,j] I get an error message.  Parse works fine the first time I use words[] but not the second time I read something in.

Comment: What is the input file? what error do you get?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: In the interest of clarity you should probably put the error message you are getting into the question itself. Also you should clarify if that sample data is the sample output or input?

Comment: How are you not getting an `indexOutOfBounds` error on your first line `3` when you read that line and then try to set `matrix1W` to `words[1]`

Comment: do you have one space between each value in your input file or do they have multiple spaces as shown?

Comment: Multiple spaces

Comment: why are you using indexing your matrix on `1` in stead of `0`?

Comment: easier to remember that point is in 1,1 instead of 0,0.  When I think of the first data point in a table I dont think of it being in 0,0

Comment: that's mostly fine but the way you are doing it leaves you with an empty column and row.  it also wastes memory but in most cases that probably won't matter.

Answer (score -2):

The issue is reading the next line from inside of your inner loop.  You need to read the line on a row instead of per cell.

```
var numOfMatrix = int.Parse(fileIn.ReadLine().Trim());
var matrices = new int[numOfMatrix][,];
for (var matrixNumber = 0; matrixNumber < numOfMatrix; matrixNumber++)
{
    var nameOfMatrix1 = fileIn.ReadLine().Trim();
    var words = fileIn.ReadLine().Trim().Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var matrix1H = int.Parse(words[0]);
    var matrix1W = int.Parse(words[1]);

    var matrix1 = matrices[matrixNumber] = new int[matrix1H, matrix1W];            
    // don't use <=
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1H; i++)
    {
        // read line line outside of the inner loop
        words = fileIn.ReadLine().Trim().Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        // don't use <=
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix1W; j++)
        {
            matrix1[i, j] = int.Parse(words[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see where that could affect things, but I am still getting the same error on the same line when running my program.

Comment: How can you be so sure this answer is correct without even knowing what the input data is in the OP's program.

Comment: because if he was to check `words[k]` on his machine when the exception is throw he will see it says `Matrix`

Comment: His input data is provided in the question.

Comment: if you are using more than one space you will also want to remove empty entires.